# Run GitHub workflow from non-gradle project

Tags: github-actions

I have a non-gradle root project which should launch child gh action, but can’t figure out how to. File `child.yml` should generate apk artifact, since `android/` dir is app directory.

Project structure:

```
root
    |
     --- .github/workflows/root.yml
     --- android/
                |
                 ___ .github/actions/apk/child.yml
```

Closest I get was running a yaml on root level:

*root.yml*

```yaml
name: use my action
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - ci_test
jobs:
  #Build job
  test_build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: ./android/.github/actions/apk
```

*child.yml*

```yaml
name: Build of dev branch
on:
    push:
        branches:
        - develop
jobs:

  #Build job
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.gradle/caches
            ~/.gradle/wrapper
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle*') }}-${{ hashFiles('**/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties') }}-${{ hashFiles('**/buildSrc/**/*.kt') }}

      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '11'

      - name: Change wrapper permissions
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew
      - name: Build the app
        run: ./gradlew assembleDebug

      - name: Upload apk
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: debug apk
          path: ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

But I get an error with doubled "/my-root-dir/my-root-dir"

`Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/my-root-dir/my-root-dir/android/.github/actions/child.yaml'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?`

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. 1. Workflows can only exist in the root .github folder. 2. You are trying to reference child.yaml as a step so GitHub is expecting it to be an action (thus the action.yml). See: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/finding-and-customizing-actions#adding-an-action-from-the-same-repository

Comment: thx for the fast reply. Ive updated the question, what about doubled `/my-root-dir/my-root-dir/android` path ? It should be single `/my-root-dir/android`

Comment: If you want child.yml to run as it is defined, you only need to place it in .github/workflows. You do not need root.yml

Comment: Root directory cannot run child.yml since it’s not Gradle repository